# camera stuck at player feet unreal engine 5.1

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am working in unreal engine 5.1. I have the problem that the camera is stuck at the player feet, and when I go into the blue print player character to edit the position of the camera, no details show up in the details panel when I click on the camera. I have followed the "Setting Up Character Movement" tutorial for C++ on the unreal engine documentation, and at no point did they adress this or add anything in the code that would change the position of the camera. The link to this tutorial is `https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.2/en-US/setting-up-character-movement/`.

I tried googling the problem, asking chatGPT, etc., and nothing helped. I tried activating the camera with the cameraComp->Activate() function, I tried adjusting the different variables of the spring arm component and camera such as socket offset, target arm length (for the springarmcomp) and additiveOffset (for the camera), but the camera won't budge. I want to have a third person camera that trails behind the player.
Here's a picture of the error occuring in play mode (I am looking up to give perspective as to where the camera is in relation to the mesh):
[image: problem]
Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/jjk4q61y
image of not seeing anything in the details panel when i have the camera component selected:
[image: details not showing]

Comment: Need more details. If the camera is connected properly to the spring arm, it should work properly.

Comment: If you are stuck, check your setup once more. Refer to [this video](https://youtu.be/Z9zEEY7dGaM?si=QyBtF3K2iVAjRQrv).

Comment: BTW, please post some code if you want help. C++ code should be similar to Blueprints.

Comment: ok i have added my code. i don't know what you mean by "need more details" though

Comment: I watched the video you sent, it's completely different from the way i'm doing it. I'm using c++, not blueprints, and the camera is created in the c++.

Comment: The only part of the project that contains blueprints is the animtion blueprints.

Comment: @kiner_shah I have added more details to the question, so if you want to look at the image of the details not showing up in the details panel, it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I had to use this code:

```
SpringArmComp->bDoCollisionTest = false;
```

Comment: So what did setting this flag to false do? Was the camera colliding with something before?

Comment: i think it was colliding with the player's capsule collider.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Better to include this in your answer as well, can be helpful.